# How do differentiate a partial derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I have $f(x, y)$ where $y$ is a function of $x$. So $f(x,y)=f(x, y(x))$. How do I differentiate the partial derivative
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)=?$$
$$\frac{d}{dy}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)=?$$

Comment: By using the chain rule. See this answer of mine : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4812696/rule-to-calculate-derivative-of-function-which-is-a-binary-operation-between-two/4812829#4812829

Comment: what does $\dot x$ and $\dot y$ stand for in your linked post?

Comment: The dot denotes derivative with respect to $t$. In the present case, you have $t = x$.

Answer (score 4):

When you find yourself getting confused in a situation like this, it is time to get explicit and pedantic.

Write $f$ as $f(X,Y)$, where
$ X(x) = x$
$ Y(x) = y(x)$.

Now you can consider the function $g(x) = f(X(x), Y(x))$, if you want to. But you should write anything you're curious about in terms of these variables, to make sure that what you're asking about is meaningful.

Notice that if you do that, the only meaningful lowest-level derivatives are

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial X}, \frac{\partial f}{\partial Y}, \frac{dY}{dx} \textrm{ [or } y'(x)\textrm{], and }\frac{dX}{dx} \textrm{ [or } 1\textrm{]}$$
along with their higher-order relatives.
I'm still thinking about it, but I'm starting to suspect that the two things you've written aren't actually meaningful - $\frac{d}{dy}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)$ looks particularly suspicious. You should provide more detail on where they came from.

Added after some comments:

Okay, it sounds like you're curious about the function $\frac{\partial f}{\partial Y}$, which I'm going to call

$$h(X,Y) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial Y}(X,Y)$$

And you say you want to treat $X$ and $Y$ as *dependent* variables, which means you want to just consider them along the path in $(X,Y)$ space defined by $(x,y(x))$. So the function you want to differentiate is

$$k(x) = h(X(x), Y(x))$$

(I'll note that you say you want $dk$, where "$d$" is usually some sort of total derivative. But when your function is a function of only one variable, say $s(t)$, then $ds$ is just $s'(t)dt$, i.e. it's not that much different from just computing $\frac{d}{dt}$ of $s$.)

So, back to $k$. Looking at its definition, we can see that it is set up perfectly for the chain rule:

$$\frac{d}{dx}k = \frac{\partial h}{\partial X}\frac{dX}{dx} + \frac{\partial h}{\partial Y}\frac{dY}{dx}$$

and substituting back all the intermediary function names we used to help us keep things straight, we get

$$\frac{d}{dx}k = \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial X \partial Y}\cdot 1 + \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial Y^2}\cdot y'(x)$$

We can, at this point, go back and look at the two expressions you originally asked about:

- The first, $\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)$, roughly corresponds to the first term of our answer, although we see that "$\partial x$" is what makes sense, not "$dx$", and also that it really isn't "equal" to something else - that's as simple an expression we can have without knowing more about $f$.
- The second, $\frac{d}{dy}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)$, doesn't seem to have been involved at all. Which is lucky for me, because I still can't think what it might represent.

Comment: Why should I use chain rule instead of quotient rule here?

Comment: Yeah, my apologies there. "Chain rule" was wrong - it's just that we got a lot of questions that look like yours that are examples of the chain rule. I have done a major edit to my answer.

Comment: I am trying to compute $d\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)$ w.r.t $x$. I thought it makes sense to compute the derivative first.

Comment: Do you want to do that along the curve in $(X,Y)$ space given by $(x,y(x)$, or do you want to look at $\frac{\partial f}{\partial Y}$ as a function of $X$ and $Y$ as two independent variables?

Comment: I want to look at $\frac{\partial f}{\partial Y}$ as a function of $X$ and $Y$ as dependent variables. Not independent. Does that make sense?

Comment: @crr1210 - You should probably add something related to your last comment there to your original question, so that other people can more easily understand the context of this answer.

Comment: JonathanZ: please don't answer problem statement questions, i.e, questions that merely state a problem and expect someone (you, in this case), to answer for them.